# Performance issue when using parameter in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, performance, view, parameter-passing

I am having a performance issue on a query, and I have no idea why it's happening. 
This query is called through a Stored Procedure, but as a matter of testing, the issue is happening with both execution ways (T-SQL or St. Proc).
I am executing a SELECT statement on a VIEW, using a parameter to define the resultset. The parameter @coligada means affiliated company id.
It's something like this:

```
DECLARE @coligada INT
SET @coligada = 1

SELECT id1, id2, code1, code2, code3, date, value1, name1, name2 
FROM view_financialcube
WHERE 
coligada = @coligada
AND date >= DATEADD(d,1,dbo.function_LastWorkingDay('01/01/2014'))
AND date <= DATEADD(m,1,'01/01/2014')
AND userid = 'elida'
```

So when I execute, the query lasts several minutes (I didnt wait for the end when it reached 10 minutes..)

Then, I tried the same query, this time without passing coligada as parameter:

```
SELECT id1, id2, code1, code2, code3, date, value1, name1, name2 
FROM view_financialcube
WHERE 
coligada = 1
AND date >= DATEADD(d,1,dbo.function_LastWorkingDay('01/01/2014'))
AND date <= DATEADD(m,1,'01/01/2014')
AND userid = 'elida'
```

This exectution took only 5 seconds to be done.

Because this statement is called in different situations depending on coligada as parameter, I need to understand why is it taking so long, and solve it.

Does anyone have a hint?

Thank you so much!

Élida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing @coligada as a local variable, not a parameter.  Consequently, the value is not known at compile time so SQL Server uses the average density statistic to determine the optimal plan.  With the literal, the value is known at compile time so the plan is chosen based on the estimated cardinality of the actual value from the statistics histogram (assuming column is indexed).

You might try parameterizing the query like the example below.  You might consider adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint to the query to avoid "parameter sniffing" issues:

```
DECLARE @coligada INT;
SET @coligada = 1;

EXEC sp_executesql
    N'SELECT id1, id2, code1, code2, code3, date, value1, name1, name2 
    FROM view_financialcube
    WHERE 
    coligada = @coligada
    AND date >= DATEADD(d,1,dbo.function_LastWorkingDay(''20140101''))
    AND date <= DATEADD(m,1,''20140101'')
    AND userid = ''elida'';',
    N'@coligada int'
    ,@coligada = @coligada;
```